# Collapse all on items by default ng-bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

Have 2 things here: Entity management and company.

Currently when i click on entity management, company will be hidden. But what i want is company to be collapsed by default.

Then when i click on entity management, it will show.

```
  <li> <a (click)="isCollapsed=!isCollapsed" aria-controls="collapseExample"><i class="icon-interface-windows"></i>Entity Management</a></li>
  <div id="collapseExample" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
    <li><a routerLink="/job"> <i class="icon-interface-windows"></i>Company</a></li>
  </div>
```

[image]

Referencing to:
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse/examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ts file add

```
isCollapsed = true;
```