# Uncollapse one item at a time using ng-bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

Really thankful for the help provided.
Although the previous issue is resolved, but pressing one category E.g. entity management will uncollapse both entity management and staff management.

I do not want to uncollapse all categories when i press one category. Collapsing all categories when i press one category is fine but not the other way round.

Any ideas on resolving this bug?

```
    </ul><span class="heading">Settings</span>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li> <a (click)="isCollapsed=!isCollapsed" aria-controls="collapseExample"><i class="icon-interface-windows"></i>Staff Management</a></li>
      <div id="collapseExample" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
        <li><a routerLink="/staff">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Access Rights</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/staff">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Staff Details</a></li>
      </div>
      <li> <a (click)="isCollapsed=!isCollapsed" aria-controls="collapseExample"><i class="icon-interface-windows"></i>Entity Management</a></li>
      <div id="collapseExample" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
        <li><a routerLink="/company">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Company</a></li>
      </div>
    </ul>
```

Prev post: [Collapse all on items by default ng-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57922586/collapse-all-on-items-by-default-ng-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out my mistake

Just add in another variable at ts

```
isCollapsedStaff = true;
```

Then update the html file with the updated variable

```
 <li> <a (click)="isCollapsedStaff=!isCollapsedStaff" aria-controls="collapseExample1"><i class="icon-interface-windows"></i>Staff Management</a></li>
          <div id="collapseExample" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsedStaff">
```